# Cannot implicitly convert type string to byte[]

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, encoding

I have a class that encrypts a password with a salted hash.

But If I want to pass a null to the class I get the following error: `Cannot implicitly convert type string to byte[]`

Here is the class code:

```
public class MyHash
{
    public static string ComputeHash(string plainText, 
                            string hashAlgorithm, byte[] saltBytes)
    {
        Hash Code
    }
}
```

When I use the class I get the error: "Cannot implicitly convert type string to byte[]"

```
//Encrypt Password
byte[] NoHash = null;
byte[] encds = MyHash.ComputeHash(Password, "SHA256", NoHash);
```

Comment: Are `string`s supposed to be convertible to `byte[]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of your `ComputeHash` function is a `string`. You try to assign the result of your function to `encds`, which is `byte[]`. The compiler points this discrepancy out to you, because there is no implicit conversion from `string` to `byte[]`.

Answer (score 15):

This is because your 'ComputeHash' method returns a string, and you are trying to assign this return value to a byte array with;

```
byte[] encds = MyHash.ComputeHash(Password, "SHA256", NoHash);
```

There is no *implicit* converstion for string to byte[] because there exist a number of different encodings to represent a string as bytes, such as ASCII or UTF8.

You need to **explicitly** convert the bytes using an appropriate encoding class like so;

```
string x = "somestring";
byte[] y = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x);
```