# How to Convert String to Byte Array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am getting an error reading:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'String' to 'Byte[]'

I think  'byte[]' is byte array - if it isn't please correct me.

I have tried another solution on this website but I did not understand. I'm making a c# 'RTM tool' and this is what put in :

```
byte[] bytes = (metroTextBox2.Text);   
Array.Resize<byte>(ref bytes, bytes.Length + 1);   
PS3.SetMemory(0x2708238, bytes);
```

Comment: You should not be using a string.  Explain what you are doing.  Reading a file as a string and then converting to byte[] will get you wrong answer. try this byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(metroTextBox2.Text);

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792315/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-byte

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
string str= "some string";
var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```

And to decode:

```
var decodeString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this hasn't worked for me, probably because i stuffed up on my end :) Sorry, thanks for helping.

Comment: @JacobReid:- You are welcome. I am not sure as to what problem you are facing as this approach works for most of the time!

Comment: Im not getting an error at the moment which is great, but its still giving not doing what i want it to do, not your fault, problem on my end thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inputStr = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inputStr);
        string str = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);
        Console.WriteLine(inputStr == str); // true
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

n byte to string conversion

```
static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
{
    char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
    return new string(chars);
}
```

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23349903/472495).

Comment: Well, I think a link in the comment would have been enough if you posted this answer. If you know what I mean.

Comment: I think now its ok.. ;)

Comment: Didn't work, thank you for trying though, much appreciated :)

Comment: Is it the same answer as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp

Comment: Yes , and it was posted multiple times, so I can share one more link but it is always better to post answer rather than link.